# NextJS deployed to AWS Amplify with ISR - build takes too long

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, server-side-rendering, aws-amplify

By default, while deploying the NextJS app to AWS Amplify, it uses 7GB RAM. When I build my app on EC2 instance with 2GB RAM (1vCPU), building app takes less than a minute, whereas, when the app builds on AWS Amplify, it takes a few minutes. Is there a way to analyze why this happens and reduce the time AWS Amplify takes to build?

By build time, I am not including the time for provisioning or other tasks. I am talking about build time only.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is building the SSR Edge Lambdas takes a long time, especially for them to provision.

Amplify people have acknowledged this and are fixing but no ETA yet sadly.

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/2127

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems that AWS Amplify gets in regards to build time is that it uses CloudFront. Cloudfront does not support instant invalidations and propagation of CDNs. As a result, AWS Amplify is bottlenecked by CloudFront to a great extent.